# How do I use the "Optional Tag" field in the GUI light wallet?

Tags: optional-tag

- What exactly is this field for?
- What format is the "tag" supposed to be in?
- Does the recipient see it? Does this info survive a snapshot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It just adds an user-defined tag to your transaction.

#### Format

It contains **27** trytes (=uppercase **ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ** and the number **9**)

- If you enter "MY9CUSTOM9TAG" the actual tag will be `MY9CUSTOM9TAG99999999999999`
- If you leave the field empty, the tag will be `999999999999999999999999999`

---

- The recipient sees it.
- It can be viewed in Tangle explorers (like [thetangle.org](https://thetangle.org))
- It does not survive snapshots but you can still look at it in Tangle explorers that support viewing transactions before snapshots

---

#### Current usage

- If you want to quickly find your transaction you can add a tag (e.g. `BRENT9BUTLER`) to your transactions and search by tag in a Tangle explorer
- You can leave friendly messages with your transfers

Comment: To add to current usage: attaching a customer reference or similar can work well